# Integer.MIN_VAL is still showing negative value

Tags: java, integer

Can anyone shed some light on why j is still holding a negative value.

```
   int i=Integer.MIN_VALUE;
   System.out.println(i);  //output, -2147483648
   int  j=-i;
   System.out.println(j);  // output, -2147483648
```

Comment: Please add a tag with the language you are using (click on "edit" at the bottom of question).

Comment: Because JAVA's `Integer.MAX_VALUE` is `2147483647`. Why it fallback to MIN_VALUE I don't know. Maybe some JAVA guru will explain that.

Answer (score 2):

[Integer.MIN_VALUE](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#MIN_VALUE) is -2<sup>31</sup> (`0x80000000`), and Integer.MAX_VALUE is 2<sup>31</sup>-1 (`0x7fffffff`).

If you negate Integer.MIN_VALUE you would get 2<sup>31</sup>, which is 1 more than Integer.MAX_VALUE, so it won't fit. Going beyond the maximum value, it wraps around into negative values.

Computers compute the negation of a value `a` as follows: `NOT(a) + 1`.
So, lets say we want to calculate `-1` by negating `1`:

- we take `0x00000001`,
- apply the NOT: `0xffffffe`
- increment: `0xffffffff`.

And in reverse, negating -1:

- take `0xffffffff`
- apply NOT: `0x00000000`
- increment: `0x00000001`

Similarly, negating -2<sup>31</sup>:

- Take `0x80000000`
- NOT: `0x7fffffff` (Integer.MAX_VALUE)
- increment: `0x80000000` (Integer.MIN_VALUE)

Answer (score 1):

```
Integer.MIN_VALUE = -2147483648
Integer.MAX_VALUE =  2147483647
```

So if you switch the sign of the `MIN_VALUE`, you're supposed to get 2147483648 which is an overflow.